# Text Analytics Vs Natural Language Processing What is the difference?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, uima

I had a tough evening today trying to convince one of my colleagues that NLP or **Natural Language Processing** is the super set and ***Text Analytics*** is a sub set of it.
At the best probably both are synonymous and can be used interchangeably.

Is that correct? Anybody who has a crystal clarity as to whether these terms have a boundary well defined or can be used interchangeably?

Comment: I would say NLP is a superset of Text Analytics if you consider everything covered by each field.  However, how the terms are used is far more important than how they are defined when talking with colleagues.  I would say some people use them as if they are interchangeable even though technically NLP contains more.

Answer (score 2):

Natural Language Processing is not bound to text only. Consider e.g. speech recognition and processing of speech - or even sign language which is visually communicated.

Simple text analytics may not qualify as natural language processing. E.g. you can use regular expression pattern matching for basic information extraction tasks but that is probably not the kind of linguistics-driven analysis that many people have in mind when thinking of NLP.

Comment: http://www.expertsystem.com/natural-language-processing-and-text-mining/ I am confused by this post. Please have a look and advise.

Comment: I disagree with the second paragraph in that I would claim it is part of NLP.  NLP is not strictly a bunch of machine-learning or statistical procedures, rather it is a balance of rule-based and learning-based methods.  Regex is a skill every NLP expert **needs** to have

Comment: There seems to be some confusion and/or controversy around this, but automatic speech recognition (ASR) is usually not considered part of natural language processing (NLP). 

*Language technology*, on the other hand, is an umbrella term which encompasses speech technology (including ASR) on the one hand, and NLP, usually considered to deal only with written language, on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Natural Language Processing is more about linguistic and study about grammatically structure of text or speech but text mining just focus on text and some specific applications.

Comment: NLP includes all forms of speech: text, verbal, non-verbal (image, video, signs as in signboards). Text specifically refers to text. In most of the cases a meta data is extracted from the huge corpus of text, image or video file received and a meaning or cognitive decision making is extracted, correlated with existing information.

Comment: I disagree as I would say your definition is more the definition of computational linguistics and not NLP.  For me, NLP is the more practical side of this field.  In industry, I find that a Text Analyst and an NLP Engineer do most of the same work.